# Out of memory error while starting JVM from within Make

Tags: jvm, makefile

I am experiencing a very strange problem. I am able to launch the Oracle JVM standalone, but when I invoke the same command through GNU `make`, I get an error.

```
> java -Xmx2500m -version
java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)

> cat Makefile
all:
    java -Xmx2500m -version

> make
java -Xmx2500m -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Btw, I am able to successfully launch the JVM with the same arguments through a shell script. So there must be something specific about how `make` launches child processes.

I have tried searching for a solution, but no luck.

My machine has 6GB RAM. The OS is Ubuntu 12.10 32bit (although I have a 64bit machine I am stuck with 32bit OS).

Comment: try to decrease the Xmx of the makefile and see if both javas are the same version.

Comment: @Karussell Good idea. I did try that too, and they are the same `java`. I even did a `which java` inside the Makefile and they are on the same path.

Comment: For which Xmx setting the maky-java does NOT fail and the normal java will fail? So, what is the difference in MB?

Comment: There may be some environment variables that are changing between the two (i.e., CLASSPATH) and causing subtle problems.

Comment: @Karussell The maky-java is breaking after 1820m. Curiously at 1821m it gives a different error than usual, and dumps a log file: https://gist.github.com/4084734

Comment: @HRJ really strange ... normally you have at least 2gb (2.7 or 2.5 as you have for your normal java). I'm really curious what this could be. would you mind trying to find out the JAVA_OPTS and if they differ? maybe the maky-java has a lot more perm-gen space reserved?

Comment: @Karussell I don't think JAVA_OPTS was set for normal java as well as maky-java. I have installed Ubuntu 64bit today and everything works fine in it with the exact same user environment. Not sure if system environment is different though.